# How do I setup keyboard shortcuts to bookmarklets in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, bookmarklet

I'm using the wonderful bookmarklet [**Readability**](http://lab.arc90.com/experiments/readability/) by **Arc90**, and it's been useful to the point where I almost always load it on pages I intend to read.

I'm using Firefox 3.5 and/or 3.6 (it depends on if I'm at home or at work), and so far I've been using the following combination of keys to apply Readability:

- (one time only) set up a keyword 'r' to the bookmarklet
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to go to the address bar
- Type 'r'
- Type 'Enter'

I'd like to be able to launch the Readability bookmarklet with a keyboard shortcut (for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>), but at the same time I'd like not to have too complex solutions (I could try and catch the keys with [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey), but I'd like a browser-only solution if possible).

What's the best way of doing this in Firefox? Is it possible in other browsers (if Chrome is doing this, that may be the proverbial straw on the proverbial camel ;) )?

Comment: The `Bookmark Keys` extension for firefox is not updated since 2.0.0 (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3647/). Owner is ready to handover development for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the [SiteLauncher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10127/) add-on to Firefox will help :

> SiteLauncher is an add-on for Firefox
>   that gives you a super-quick way to to
>   open your favorite websites using only
>   your keyboard. One special hotkey
>   brings up the 'Launcher', followed by
>   a unique key to launch a site.

It is claimed that it works correctly for bookmarklets, even if 'Open shortcuts in new tab' is checked.

[image]

Comment: SiteLauncher no longer exists for more recent versions of Firefox.  (The same is true of Bookmark Keys, mentioned in a comment above, though there's another extension with the same name that is unrelated to keyboard shortcuts.)